# How to use React Context value from a separate JSS styles component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-context, react-with-styles

I have moved my react jss styles to another file. Now I am using React context to toggle `thememode`. And I want to change the styles when `thememode` toggles from true to false and vice versa.

But since my component styles are on a new file, I can't access `useContext` from there. It says cannot use `useContext` outside of a React function. So I can't change styles and colors when `thememode` is changed.

Is there any way that I can get the `thememode` or access the value of my context?

> what I have tried:

I tried putting `thememode` as a prop in  `withStyles(styles(thememode))(Mycomponent)`, but I can't even access `thememode` constant outside of the function to which I have grabbed the `thememode` value using usecontext.

Comment: Can you post some code? Maybe a stripped down codesandbox to show the problem?

Comment: its a project, 30+ components

Comment: What I want is to get useContext outside of a react component

Comment: Like a JSS stylesheet which only returns object and I use it inside my component using withStyles

Comment: You cannot use react hooks outside of a react component

Comment: So how does sites like material-ui changes their dark theme, they must put all their JSS styles inside of each component

Comment: I don't think they use JSS: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/package.json
Here's their ThemeProvider https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-styles/src/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js

Comment: You should be changing the theme specified by your ThemeProvider. See my example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145165/change-root-background-color-with-material-ui-theme/59145819#59145819.

Comment: I have specified my theme in my ThemeContext and grabbed it in my functional component. But since my styles are in another file which returns an object, I can't access them from there.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their time, I am trying inline styles for now

Comment: `withStyles` provides the theme, you don't need to get it from context so long as it is specified in the `ThemeProvider` appropriately.