# Material-ui does not change Typography color according to theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying out material-ui, so I have create two themes:

```
const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

const lightTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light"
  }
});
```

But when I use `Typography` component its color property does not change. Even more - color is inherited from `html` so `Typography` is unaware of current theme.
Is there way to configure Typography color while creating theme or use default? 
I have tried to put `color` prop in pallete object like so:

```js
const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    typography: {
       body1: {
           color: '#fff'
       }
    }

  }
});
```

But had no luck. I've create [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-typography-tfnno?file=/src/App.js). And there I have discovered that if I downgrade `material-ui` to `3.1` it works fine - `.MuiTypography-body1` class sets color property corresponding to theme.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The default behavior for `Typography` is to do nothing with color. The reason for this is that generally the color is controlled by the same component that is controlling the background color. For instance, if you put the `Typography` element within a `Paper` element, the `Paper` will control both `background-color` and `color`. In order to have the html and body elements honor your theme, you need to use `CssBaseline`.

`Typography` provides the `color` prop for explicitly controlling the color. Using `color="textPrimary"` will [set the color of the Typography](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui/src/Typography/Typography.js#L89) in the same way as [CssBaseline sets the color for the body element](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui/src/CssBaseline/CssBaseline.js#L15).

Below is a working example demonstrating the behavior:

```
import React from "react";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

const lightTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light"
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const [topLevelDark, setTopLevelDark] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={topLevelDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          setTopLevelDark(!topLevelDark);
        }}
      >
        Toggle Themes
      </Button>
      <div>
        <Typography variant="body1">I'm within the top-level theme</Typography>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={topLevelDark ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
          <Paper>
            <Typography variant="body1">
              I'm in a Paper within the nested theme
            </Typography>
          </Paper>
          <Typography variant="body1" color="textPrimary">
            I'm in the nested theme with textPrimary color, but outside of a
            Paper. This makes me hard to read since nothing is setting the
            background-color to something contrasting.
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body1">
            I'm in the nested theme outside of a Paper with no explicit color.
          </Typography>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit material-ui-typography]

---

**A note about using multiple themes**

In your code sandbox example, you had two sibling `ThemeProvider` elements, but when using your own custom theme it is important for your custom theme to be at the top-level. If you use a different theme for part of the page, it should be nested within your top-level theme. If you have two top-level ThemeProvider elements (i.e. neither one nested within the other), they will both be trying to impact the global Material-UI CSS class names. This means that only one of them will win, and the other won't seem to work at all. When Material-UI detects that you are within a nested ThemeProvider, it will use different (suffixed) class names within the nested theme, and the nested theme will work as expected.

Related answers:

- [Change root background color with Material-UI theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145165/change-root-background-color-with-material-ui-theme/59145819#59145819)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's shame that is not described in docs and works in prev versions - I have spend hours looking for solution

Comment: @KostyaTresko It is documented in the v3 to v4 migration guide: https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/#typography

Comment: Just adding `<CssBaseline />` worked for me. Thanks!!!

Comment: So basically if I have Typography all by itself, it'll do nothing unless wrapped in a `Card` or `Paper`?? Because I'm running into this same issue right now I think, and I've noticed it picks up the primary colors and everything if it's wrapped within a `Paper` component but not a `Box` component.

Comment: @glitchwizard Correct, `Typography` has no effect on color unless you specify the color prop explicitly. `Box` has no effect on anything (it's just a `<div>`) except the effect of whatever props you pass to it.