# Typography component not accepting 'color' inside sx

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've been experiencing an issue in which I cannot apply 'color' inside the 'sx' property of a Typography component. Does anyone know what might be causing the issue?

[image: image of the result]

Removing the 'color' key causes the color of the 2 line to be reverted to default (same as the 1st line).

```
import React from 'react';
import {Box, createTheme, CssBaseline, Typography} from '@mui/material';
import {ThemeProvider} from '@mui/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
  },
});

console.log(theme);

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Box
        sx={{
          height: '100%',
          bgcolor: 'background.paper',
          color: 'text.primary',
        }}>
        1111111111111111
        <Typography sx={{color: 'text.secondary'}}>
          22222222222222222
        </Typography>
        <Box sx={{color: 'text.secondary'}}>333333333333</Box>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Typography` component doesn't directly support theming and color schemes you have to do it manually in your palette, or you can simply use `Box` component or rather don't give color inside `sx` property

or you can do something like that

```
  <Typography color='GrayText'>
          22222222222222222
  </Typography>
```

[image: This is the result]

for more deep information refer to this answer about why `Typography` doesn't change color on theme change

([Material-ui does not change Typography color according to theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520960/material-ui-does-not-change-typography-color-according-to-theme))